# connection timed out; no servers could be reached when using dig to query dns in kvm machine

Tags: domain-name-system

When I am using this command to dig dns in my KVM virtual machine(CentOS 8):

```
[root@k8sslave1 ~]# dig www.stackoverflow.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.13-RedHat-9.11.13-3.el8 <<>> www.stackoverflow.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

and this is my resolv.conf `vim /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 114.114.115.115
```

when I ping IP of internet, it works fine. For exmaple:

```
[root@k8sslave1 ~]# ping 114.114.115.115
PING 114.114.115.115 (114.114.115.115) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 114.114.115.115: icmp_seq=1 ttl=89 time=21.2 ms
64 bytes from 114.114.115.115: icmp_seq=2 ttl=91 time=20.5 ms
64 bytes from 114.114.115.115: icmp_seq=3 ttl=83 time=20.8 ms
```

without dns resolve, I could not work in the virtual mahcine, I could not access any resource, and could not install software. so where is going wrong? what should I do fix this problem? This is my KVM virtual machine firewalld status:

```
[root@k8sslave1 ~]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a firewall blocking domain queries?   That is normally port 53.

Comment: firewalld disabled doesn't mean there isn't a firewall (on the slave or on the host - what should we call those now?).  Then: what name server is running, if any, on 114.114.115.115?   In stead of the ping test, try  "telnet 114.114.115.115 53".  But DNS is UDP, while telnet is TCP.  "nslookup" is another way to test.